# Can't get CLIq to go beyond first screen

Tags: data-loader

If I click on Next

[image]

I get the error

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.salesforce.dataloader.security.EncryptionUtil.encryptString(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/String;
        at com.salesforce.cliq.cliconfig.CliConfig.encryptPassword(CliConfig.java:335)
        at com.salesforce.cliq.cliconfig.CliConfig.setPassword(CliConfig.java:349)
        at com.salesforce.cliq.cliconfig.CliConfig.setConfigDefaults(CliConfig.java:216)
        at com.salesforce.cliq.cliconfig.CliConfigExport.setConfigDefaults(CliConfigExport.java:61)
```

Works perfectly fine on my work computer though.
Might be using a few API older version of data loader on the work computer.
What should I do?
If I need an older version of data loader, where do I get it?
No, Google wasn't my friend, all links are broken.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CLIq works fine with Data Loader 43.0 on my office laptop (Toshiba Portege).

CLIq works with [Data Loader 42.0](https://github.com/forcedotcom/dataloader/releases/download/V42.0/ApexDataLoader.exe) on my home laptop (Surface Pro), but doesn't work with 43.0

### Step by step screenshot guide for setting up CLIq:

https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/salesforce-cliq-1-click-data-loading-your-entire-sandbox-saha/